# Ocultar Columna de tabla en Power BI

Tags: tablas, powerbi, microsoft, visualización-de-datos, dax

En mi trabajo se me pidio si era posible ocultar una columna de una tabla de power BI,
Supongamos que tengo una tabla X, con N cantidad de columnas, y con con una respectiva aplicacion de filtros una de las columnas esta vacia.

Entonces la idea es que cuando esto ocurra, esta columna vacia no se muestre.

Nota: Los bookmarks no son una alternativa

Comment: La respuesta es simple: no es posible hacerlo. Las columnas son las que introduces en el visual, no hay un mecanismo para ocultarlas, tampoco una forma condicional para hacerlo.